# HTML 5 - very simple animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-sprites

I need to understand how to create a simple animation in HTML 5 or CSS3.

Suppose you have this sprite (see picture) and you need to create an animation with 4 frames. The animation has to last exactly 1 second. I don't want a smooth animation between the frames, I want it to jump from one state to the other without interpolation. These are the ball 4 frames:

```
                  X        Y      ROTATION       OPACITY (%)
First frame:     100      220        10            5
Second frame:    150      240        18            25
Third frame:     160      280        32            55
Fourth frame:    170      290        47            78
```

In resume, every 0.25s the ball has to assume one of these keyframes. No loop on the animation.

Can you guys give an example on how to do that using CSS or HTML5/Javascript? (the method that produces the less CPU intensive approach). Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Use `transform: rotate` in css3 and setTimeout in javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with pure CSS3 using [`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@keyframes), [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_animations), [`transform: rotate(angle) translate(x,y);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform#rotate) and [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/opacity).

Here's an example (using the `-webkit-` vendor prefix, use `-moz-`, `-o-`, `-ms-` for optimal compatibility): http://jsfiddle.net/QaPaK/
**The example only works in Chrome and Safari, because I did not add the other prefixes for a compact example.**

HTML (animating an `<img>` element, for example):

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLNOU.png" id="test">​
```

CSS:

```
/* Replace -webkit- with moz-, -o-, -ms- for cross-browser compatibility */
#test {
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-animation-name: foo;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes foo {
    0%, 25% { /* State 1 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg) translate(100px, 200px);
        opacity: 0.05;
    }
    25%, 50% { /* State 2 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(18deg) translate(150px, 240px);
        opacity: 0.25;
    }
    50%, 75% { /* State 3 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(32deg) translate(160px, 280px);
        opacity: 0.55;
    }
    75%, 100% { /* State 4 */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(47deg) translate(170px, 290px);
        opacity: 0.78;
    }
}
```

Comment: care to give an example? can CSS3 handle the precision of showing each keyframe at the exact moment?

Comment: @Otterly Added an example. The "animation" jumps from state 1 to 2 to 3 to 4.

Comment: @Truth yes, I asked about rotation, translation, opacity change and scale

Comment: ahhh, thanks. Just one thing: how do I "attach" the animation to the object? Suppose I have a <div class="ball"></div> and this .ball class defines the ball image as background. Now, how do I attach this div with "ball" class to these keyframes, so the ball will execute them?

Comment: @Otterly "foo" is the name of your animation. It can be any valid identifier. Then, use the `animation-name` property to add the animation. See my example, I really used the minimum necessary code, and all properties are human-readable ("name", "duration", "iteration count").

Comment: no, what I ask is this: I understand your code what I don't see is you connecting this code to the ball object.

Comment: @Otterly In the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QaPaK/), I defined the ball as `<img src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/KLNOU.png" id="test">`. That is your "ball object".

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a few ways. Here's the way I'd actually do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/NcuZC/1/

Essentially, I'm using:

```
var changeFrame = function(elem, i) {
    elem.removeClass().addClass('frame'+i);
};

$(function() {
    var ball = $('#ball'),
        i = 1,
        timer = window.setInterval(function() {
            changeFrame(ball, i);
            i++;  
            if (i > 4) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }        
        }, 250);    
});​
```

Then in CSS a class for each frame:

```
.frame1 {
    left: 100px;
    top: 220px;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(10deg);
    /* In IE10 there is no prefix. */
    transform: rotate(10deg);

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(/* IE6–IE9 */
                     M11=0.984807753012208, M12=-0.17364817766693033, M21=0.17364817766693033, M22=0.984807753012208, sizingMethod='auto expand');

    opacity: 0.05;
    filter: alpha(opacity=5); /* IE8 down */
}
```

I didn't use CSS3 animations, despite having a popular website about it, because I've found they are CPU intensive sometimes, and also as you don't need tweening, there isn't much point.

Also, by using JS, we can get this to work in every popular browser, from IE6 to the latest Webkits.